# TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations - iterating over range of dates

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, mutable

I have two column dates(type objects which has worked for rest of my code), and am trying to split the range between these dates into two/more financial years, sum them and multiply this with day rate to get revenue and iterate this through every row in my dataframe.

I am working out revenue per person/row and have calculated this by iterating through itterows and calculating revenue = rate*number of days. Now as and extension of that i've got the range of two date columns, i want to sum the dates before and after the tax year and multiply this with rate per day. 
ive tried to include this into my iteration
    day_range[i] =  pd.bdate_range(start, end)
and it gives the type error Index does not support mutable operations. Complete code works when i dont add the [i] for all columns except th elast two lines below.
Ive also tried 
    day_range.date[i] and 
    day_range.datetime index][i]
and this gives me IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
and TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
respectively. All columns populate correctly except for the last two lines below which are my column name assignments

```
financialYear0 = []
financialYear1= []
dateString0 = []  
dateString1 = []
i = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    start = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_'][i])
    end = pd.to_datetime(df['End_'][i])
    holidays = df['Holidays'][i]       
    df['Project_Days'][i] = workdays(start, end, holidays)
    rev[i] = day[i] * rate[i]
    rev[i] = rev[i]*df['Percentage'][i]//100
    day_range.datetimeindex =  pd.bdate_range(start, end)

    for day_ in range(day_range.datetimeindex):
        date_str = datetime.datetime(day_.year, day_.month, day_.day, 0, 
0)
        date_str = day_.strftime('%m, %d, %Y')
        date_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m, %d, 
%Y").date()
        year_of_date=date_.year
        #initialize the current financial year start date
        financial_year_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("04, 01, 
" + 
        str(year_of_date), "%m, %d, %Y").date()
        #change back to string

        if date_<financial_year_start_date:
            str_date0 = datetime.datetime(date_.year, date_.month, 
date_.day, 
         0, 0)
            str_date0 = date_.strftime('%d, %m, %Y')
            dateString0.append(str_date0)
        else: 
            str_date1 = datetime.datetime(date_.year, date_.month, 
date_.day, 
         0, 0)
            str_date1 = date_.strftime('%d, %m, %Y')
            dateString1.append(str_date1)

    num_string = len(dateString0)
    num_string1 = len(dateString1)
    financialYear0[i] = num_string * rate[i]
    financialYear1[i] = num_string1 * rate[i]
```

my last two lines are giving incorrect results for second to last rows and correct for the first row. I suspect that it goes wrong when i trying to mak my day_range iterable by adding [i]

Comment: SOLVED - Moved initialisation of two arrays into loop - realised that after first loop output was wrong

Comment: Gratz on solving it. For future reference, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should be able to answer yourself to your question, then to mark the answer as accepted. That way, the question would be marked as solved

Comment: thanks @ olinox14, I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: thanks @ Tom. will do

Answer (score 1):

Moved initialisation of two arrays into loop - realised that after first loop output was wrong.